# Using Harcascading file along with Your Own Trained SVM file

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svm, feature-extraction

Can we use "Harcascading File" along with our own Trained SVM file ?
I am confuse at this spot and searched also but I couldn't find satisfactory answer.

Here is the code part:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img= cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\ATech\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\interface\\images\\face.jpg",0)

eye_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:\\Users\\ATech\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\interface\\images\\haarcascade_eye.xml")
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_load("C:\\Users\\ATech\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\interface\\images\\svm_data_lft.xml")
sample = []
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hist = hog.compute(img)
found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(img,winStride=(8,8),padding=(16,16), scale=1, useMeanshiftGrouping=False)
#print(type(found))
sample.append(hist)
print(hist)
sample = np.float32(sample)
#hist = cv2.resize(hist, (1, 1))
res = svm.predict(sample)
print (res)
eyes=eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(img,scaleFactor=1.1,minNeighbors=5)
for (x, y, w, h) in eyes:

    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), ( x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 6)

cv2.imshow("eyes detected",img
```

I would be obliged if anyone help me out and guide me how to solve this confussion

Comment: opencv's haarcascades do not use svm classifiers but cascades of decision trees, as far as I know.

Comment: means I have to use one among them ?

Comment: you can train your own with the given opencv tools and maybe with other tools.